Regulating certain integral
I am interested in regulating an integral of the type,
\begin{equation}
I = 
\frac{1}{2\pi^2}\int_0^\infty p^2\ dp\ \frac{g(p)}{p^2 - k^2 - i\epsilon}
= 
\frac{1}{4\pi^2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty p^2\ dp\ \frac{g(p)}{p^2 - k^2 - i\epsilon}
\end{equation}
with a cut-off $\Lambda$. Here, $g(p)\to 1$ as $p\to\infty$, is analytic in the complex $p$-plane and even in $p$.
To evaluate this, I tried to use complex analysis. In particular, I used the fact that
\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty
f(z)\ dz = 2\pi i\ {\rm Res}[f(z)] - \lim_{\Lambda\to\infty}\int_{C_\Lambda}f(z)\ d z
\end{equation}
where $C_\Lambda$ indicates semi-circular path with radius $\Lambda$.
This leads to
\begin{equation}
I = \frac{1}{4\pi^2}
\left\{
2\pi i \cdot \frac{k}{2}g(k) - \lim_{\Lambda\to\infty}\int_{C_\Lambda} dp\ \frac{p^2}{p^2 - k^2 - i\epsilon}
\right\}
.
\end{equation}
where we used the fact that $g(p\to\infty)\to 1$. To evaluate the integral over the semi-circle we take $p = \Lambda \exp[i\theta]$, $\theta\in [0,\pi]$. This gives,
\begin{equation}
I = \frac{1}{4\pi^2}
\left\{
 i \pi k g(k) - \lim_{\Lambda\to\infty} 
\left[
-2\Lambda + 2k\ {\rm arctanh}(\Lambda/k)
\right]
\right\}
\end{equation}
Using,
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x\to \infty} {\rm arctanh}\ x
= -i \pi/2,
\end{equation}
leads to
\begin{equation}
I = \frac{1}{4\pi^2}
\left\{
 i \pi k [g(k) + 1]  
+2\Lambda
\right\}.
\end{equation}
According to this paper, when $g(p) = 1$, the answer should be (Eq. 3.11)
\begin{equation}
\int\frac{d^3 p}{(2\pi)^3}\ \frac{1}{p^2 - k^2 - i\epsilon}
=
\frac{1}{2\pi^2}\Lambda + \frac{i}{4\pi}k,
\end{equation}
However, this is not the case give the formula I derived. Where is my mistake? Thanks!

I suspect that it should be $\text{arctanh}(k/\Lambda)$.  It is faster to Taylor expand the integrand and see that the $C_{\lambda}$ integral comes out to be $2\Lambda + O(k^2/\lambda)$.

Related Math.SE post by OP: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/5014975/11127

I asked a similar question on the Mathematics side of StackExchange (link) which more or less answered my question.
The issue here is that ${\rm arctan}\ x$ has a branch cut and so, the integral must be treated with care. In particular,
\begin{equation}
\int_{C_\Lambda} dp\ \frac{p^2}{p^2 - k^2 - i\epsilon} 
=
\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}
\left\{
\left(
\int_{\pi/2 +\epsilon}^\pi\frac{i \Lambda^3e^{3i\theta}}{\Lambda^2e^{2 i\theta} - k^2}\ d \theta
\right)
+
\left(
\int_0^{\pi/2 -\epsilon}\frac{i \Lambda^3e^{3i\theta}}{\Lambda^2e^{2 i\theta} - k^2}\ d \theta
\right)
\right\}
.
\end{equation}
Using,
\begin{equation}
\int\frac{i \Lambda^3e^{3i\theta}}{\Lambda^2e^{2 i\theta} - k^2}\ d \theta
=
\Lambda e^{i\theta}
+i
k\ {\rm arctan}
\left(
\frac{i\Lambda}{k}e^{i\theta}
\right)
\end{equation}
and the properties found here and the fact that ${\rm arctan}(ix) = i\ {\rm arctanh}(x)$ one finds
\begin{equation}
\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}
\int_{\pi/2 +\epsilon}^\pi\frac{i \Lambda^3e^{3i\theta}}{\Lambda^2e^{2 i\theta} - k^2}\ d \theta
=
-(i + 1)\Lambda 
+i
k
\left\{
\frac{1}{2}\pi - i\ {\rm arctanh}(\Lambda/k) + {\rm arctan}(\Lambda/k)
\right\} 
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}
\int_0^{\pi/2 -\epsilon}\frac{i \Lambda^3e^{3i\theta}}{\Lambda^2e^{2 i\theta} - k^2}\ d \theta
=
(i - 1)\Lambda 
+i
k
\left\{
\frac{1}{2}\pi - i\ {\rm arctanh}(\Lambda/k) - {\rm arctan}(\Lambda/k)
\right\} 
\end{equation}
Adding the two gives
\begin{equation}
\int_{C_\Lambda} dp\ \frac{p^2}{p^2 - k^2 - i\epsilon} 
=
-2\Lambda
+ 2k \ {\rm arctanh}(\Lambda/k)
+
i\pi k
.
\end{equation}
This means the correct answer, with the residue component is
\begin{equation}
I = \frac{1}{4\pi^2}
\left\{
i\pi k [g(k) - 1] + 2\Lambda - 2k\ {\rm arctanh(\Lambda/k)}
\right\}
.
\end{equation}
Then $g(k) = 1$ this reduces to
\begin{equation}
I = 
\frac{\Lambda}{2\pi^2} - \frac{k}{2\pi^2} \ {\rm arctanh}(\Lambda/k)
\end{equation}
which, in the large $\Lambda$ limit reduces to
\begin{equation}
I(\Lambda\gg k) 
\simeq \frac{\Lambda}{2\pi^2} + \frac{ik}{4\pi}
.
\end{equation}
Which is consistent with Eq. 3.11 of the paper linked in the question.
